# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error in tic tac toe

Tags: xcode, swift

After I press 'Play Again' button in my tic tac toe game it is suppose to reset every button.

When I do this :

```
for var i = 1; i < 9; i++
```

it does not crash, but it hides everything except my upper left button.

when i do this

```
for var i = 0; i < 9; i++
```

it crashes and indicates EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Apparently the breakpoint is here :

```
 if (gameState[sender.tag]==0 && winner == 0) {
```

This is the playAgainPressed action

```
@IBAction func playAgainPressed(sender : AnyObject) {
     goNumber = 1
      winner = 0
      gameState = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
      label.center = CGPointMake(label.center.x - 400, label.center.y)
      playAgain.alpha = 0

      var button : UIButton
      for var i = 0; i < 9; i++ {
          button = view.viewWithTag(i) as UIButton
          button.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
      }
}
```

0x108b7d350:  ud2

```
  if (gameState[sender.tag]==0 && winner == 0) {
```

Any thoughts?

---

I changed the tags to 100, 101 etc

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    if (gameState[sender.tag]==0){


    var image = UIImage()

    if (goNumber%2==0){
    image = UIImage(named: "o")!
        gameState[sender.tag]==2
        }else{

    image = UIImage(named: "x")!
        gameState[sender.tag]==1
    }

    goNumber++

    sender.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
   }
}
```

It is giving this error

fatal error: Array index out of range
(lldb)

and it is calling it a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION again. I have no idea what is wrong with it.

if (gameState[sender.tag]==0)

This is where it indicates there's something wrong. It marks this part above green and calls it EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION..

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  It's hard for us to help you when you don't format your code properly.  Please indent every line of code by an extra four spaces so the site will display the code properly.

Comment: Add the exact and full error messages, copy and paste into your existing question. Also what line is the crash on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EXC\_BREAKPOINT in xcode 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774548/exc-breakpoint-in-xcode-6)

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is that you have multiple views with the tag value 0 since it is the default. So you are probably getting a view that is not a `Button`. Or there may not exist.

`viewWithTag` returns an Optional and you are not testing for nil. Don't ignore testing for Optionals and don't just add an explicit unwrapping, that will just toss the Optional protections.

When using tags avoid 0. Better yet use larger tags like: 100, 101, 102 ...

Answer (score 0):

You probably already have a

@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

this code worked for me:

```
button.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
for var i = 1; i < 9; i++ {
    button = view.viewWithTag(i) as UIButton
    button.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
}
```

The app crashed all the time if I started with `i = 0` with the same warning so I just reset the button image to nil without the tag for button with tag 0. I am new to iOS programming and Swift so may only be a fix and not a true 'programmers' solution, but hope it helps.